What performance disadvantages might I face with this approach to creating a library of iterators?
I'm working on my iterator library and I've come up with what I think is a convenient API. Here are some examples of how to use it:
// API usages
const iterable = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
// First of all we have to cast iterable 
// into IterableWrapper to have ability to // chain another iterators
const iter = intoIterable(iterable)
  .filter((x) => x > 4)
  .map((x) => x + 100)
  .take(2);

// intoIterable
function intoIterable<T>(iterable: Iterable<T>): IterableWrapper<T> {
  return IterableWrapper.new(iterable);
}

// IterableWrapper
type MapFn<T, U> = (item: T) => U;
type FilterFn<T> = (item: T) => boolean;

class IterableWrapper<T> {
  iterable: Iterable<T>;
  iterator: Iterator<T>;

  constructor(iterable: Iterable<T>) {
    this.iterable = iterable;
    this.iterator = iterable[Symbol.iterator]();
  }

  static new<T>(iterable: Iterable<T>): IterableWrapper<T> {
    return new IterableWrapper(iterable);
  }

  [Symbol.iterator]() {
    return this;
  }

  next() {
    return this.iterator.next();
  }

  // Modifiers
  map<U>(fn: MapFn<T, U>): IterableWrapper<U> {
    const iter = this.iterator;
    const mapIterable = createMapIterable(iter, fn);
    const iterableWrapper = IterableWrapper.new(mapIterable);
    return iterableWrapper;
  }

  filter(fn: FilterFn<T>): IterableWrapper<T> {
    const iter = this.iterator;
    const filterIterable = createFilterIterable(iter, fn);
    const iterableWrapper = IterableWrapper.new(filterIterable);
    return iterableWrapper;
  }

  // Aggregators
  sum(this: IterableWrapper<number>): number {
    const sumResult = sum(this.iterable);
    return sumResult;
  }

  // Other
  take(n: number): IterableWrapper<T> {
    const iter = this.iterator;
    const takeIterable = createTakeIterable(iter, n);
    const iterableWrapper = IterableWrapper.new(takeIterable);
    return iterableWrapper;
  }
}

export default IterableWrapper;

// createMapIterable
type MapFn<T, U> = (item: T) => U;

function map<T, U>(iter: Iterator<T>, fn: MapFn<T, U>): Iterable<U> {
  return {
    [Symbol.iterator]() {
      return {
        next: () => {
          const { done, value } = iter.next();
          return done ? { done, value } : { done, value: fn(value) };
        },
      };
    },
  };
}

export default map;

createFilterIterable is almost the same as createMapIterable.
I have a few questions:

Performance: Is this approach effective from a performance perspective? Each time an iterator method is called, a brand new IterableWrapper is returned, which could become quite large after adding all possible iterators. Does this matter given modern JIT compilation optimizations? If my approach is not efficient, could you recommend how it could be improved without changing the API?
API Design: What do you think about the API? The contracts are pretty simple, so I don't anticipate major issues, but I'd appreciate any insights or potential pitfalls.


any iterator except some native optimized will be much slower than native JS functions: https://dev.to/alexander-nenashev/avoid-iteratorsgenerators-in-javascript-116n

What do you mean by "which could become quite large after adding all possible iterators"?

"I'm working on my iterator library and I've come up with what I think is a convenient API." - are you aware of https://github.com/tc39/proposal-iterator-helpers?

"What do you think about the API?" - the API is fine (except maybe for new IterableWrapper vs IterableWrapper.new vs intoIterable), but I don't understand what is the point of iterable: Iterable<T>;. You never do anything with it, so why not just wrap only the iterator? Also why split the implementations of map into separate files like createMapIterable, then have very repetitive method definitions?

@AlexanderNenashev nice article. Yeah, the approach with generators is the slowest. I'm going to use an approach without generators. I understand that it will be slower compared to the native implementation, but it's still the most convenient way to do it.

@Bergi, what I meant is that the code for IterableWrapper will grow significantly when more iterators are added. Each time a new iterator is invoked, a new IterableWrapper instance will be created, incorporating all initialized iterators.
Oh, I haven't seen this proposal. Anyway, working with iterators is part of my assignment for the course :)

@Bergi, why new IterableWrapper instead of IterableWrapper.new, intoIterable? I think there is no difference in how the new IterableWrapper is created at this point in time. However, in the future, maybe I may need to modify the iterable I'm creating. The most logical way for me to do this would be to move the creation logic into a new method.
iterable: Iterable do you mean it's usage in intoIterable ? I you do, then you are quite right. I've decided to do so because it looks more semathically :) But now, I really have to rethink this approach. Thanks.

"a new IterableWrapper instance will be created, incorporating all initialized iterators" - no. Adding more methods to the class only affects the prototype object. The instances themselves don't grow, they consist of only two properties and a prototype chain link.

@Bergi Oh, that's great! I didn't know that.

The real-world implementation is quite large in size for operators, you would never want it in one class. I am the author of iter-ops, and I've done plenty of those to know ;)
